# JQuery Table Mouse Over Images

Tags: jquery, image, html-table, mouseover

I have a table in my cshtml with the `id="uiViewsThumbnail"`.
Let's say my table is composed of this:

```
  <table id="uiViewsThumbnail">
         <img src="blablabla.png" >
         <img src="heyehey.png">>
  </table>
```

I want to be able to show the name of the image when you mouse over it.
I have been trying to use

```
    $('#uiViewsThumbnail img').click(function () {

    });
```

But it doesn't work. When I use `#uiViewsThumbnail` without the img, I am able to select the whole table. However, I want to mouseover specific images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use title:

```
<img src="blablabla.png" title="Image title" >
```

Check also your code. You are now using images in table. Should be used like:

```
<table>
  <tr>
   <td><img src="some" /></td>
   <td><img src="some" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```